# Splitting files by 1st character - unix

Tags: file, unix, split

I have a file as such (assume that file is sorted):

```
A213 foo bar sentence
A123 bar foo sentence
B84521 abc hello world
C984 def word hello
```

I need to split it up into three files based on the 1st character of each line:

File1:

```
A213 foo bar sentence
A123 bar foo sentence
```

File2:

```
B84521 abc hello world
```

File3:

```
C984 def word hello
```

How can I do that easily?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this `awk` to redirect all lines to an specific file name:

```
awk '{print > substr($0, 1, 1)}' file
```

Because `substr($0, 1, 1)` returns the first character of the line and `print >` redirects the output to the given file name. (Note: it starts at 1, not 0, as noted by Ed Morton in comments.)

---

Also this awk makes it, although it involves changing the field separator to make it character specific:

```
awk -v FS= '{print > $1}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{ ab = substr($0,0,1);
 if(ab == "a") { printf $0"\n" >> "/dirname/file1" }
else if(ab == "b") { printf $0"\n" >> "/dirname/file2" }
else { printf $0"\n" >> "/dirname/file3" } }
```

The above script is in file "redir". Run the script as `redir inputfilename`

Above awk splits the contents and redirects into separate files.