# Splitting files by first char

Tags: shell, file, unix, awk

I need to split a big text file by the first char of lines.

Eg i have a file like :

```
B1fe3z5 
A1g5sef 
C1gs351qz 
C02qdqz
```

Then

```
A1g5sef is copied to a.txt  
B1fe3z5 is copied to b.txt 
C02qdqz and C1gs351qz are copied to c.txt
```

I tried this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/24778211/9199179

```
awk '{print > substr($0, 0, 1)}' file
```

It's working well, but I have lines starting with some symbols like "\" which are forbidden in a file name.

> How can I redirect these lines to a specific "symbol.txt" file ?

Thank !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT2***  Have talked to OP in comments section and OP mentioned that if 
 any line starts from any alphabets or digits it should go to respective letter else it should go to another file, then one should try following.

```
awk '{if($0 ~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]/){file=substr($0, 1, 1)} else {file="symbol_file"};print >> (file);close(file)}' Input_file
```

***OR*** As per Ed sir's comment shorten form of above solution.

```
awk '{file = (/^[[:alnum:]]/ ? tolower(substr($0,1,1)) : "symbol") ".txt"; print >> file; close(file)}' Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT1:***

```
awk '{if($0~/^\\/ || $0~/^\//){file="symbol_file"} else {file=substr($0, 1, 1)};print >> (file);close(file)}' Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following once.

```
awk '{if($0~/^\\/){file=substr($0, 2, 1)} else {file=substr($0, 1, 1)};print >> (file);close(file)}' Input_file
```

***OP's approach fixes and other suggestions added:***

1- You were not closing the output files in back-end which will definitely will be problematic if you have huge Input_file and it will end up in "Too many opened files error"; so I fixed it up.

2- You are using `substr($0, 0, 1)` which shouldn't be the case; in substr`index starts from`1`not from`0`.

3- To your question on lines which are starting from `\` I have checked condition for it, if line starts with `\` then take 2nd character for Output file or take first character for Output file name.

Comment: you are the best. ty for your time